# Hand icon on div button. Behave like reall button

Tags: javascript

I really could not find that thing. For some of you it is detail but for me it is important detail.
I have a div:

```
<div id="hello" onclick="alert('hello')" onmouseover="onroll_right_icon()" onmouseout="onout_right_icon()"></div>
```

It is working fine as a button but i want that div behaviur like a real button or hiperlink. I mean i want to see a hand cursor when you onmouseover on this. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try to solve this with JavaScript. You can use the CSS [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property:

```css
#hello {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/nH8CD/)